# Assign <td> column height to the min value

Tags: css, html, html-table, nested-table

How can I create a very thin table row(with minimal height) using html/css?

I tried using `<td height, min-height>` tags. The height can be increased but not decreased beyond a certain value. The enclosed text is underscore(_) or period. So it doesn't take that much height. But for some reason I can't minimize the height of the `td`

`<td height="15px">` vs `<td height="5px">` appears the same.

I am trying to draw a background color with custom width. Any alternatives to this approach?

Comment: Use CSS, not presentational attributes.

Comment: An underscore or a period still take up vertical height corresponding to the line-height of the font.  The height of the character itself is not relevant.

Comment: @andi -  you are right, that was the issue in my case, removing the '_' lets me resize the column height now . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes to 0? Also `border-collapse: collapse;`

Answer (score 0):

According to w3schools, the TD height attribute is not supported in html5. You need to use CSS instead.